# How to pass array of string and a string as a vararg?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I want to pass an array and a single object to method which has varargs.

However, the most obvious solution doesn't seem to work:

```
public static final String[] ARRAY_ARGS =  {"first argument", "second argument"};
public static String additionalArgument = "additional argument";

public static void foo(String... args) {
    // ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(ARRAY_ARGS,additionalArgument); // error! won't compile
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple yet elegant solution using Apache Commons Lang library:

```
foo(ArrayUtils.addAll(ARRAY_ARGS,additionalArgument));
```

Comment: This won't work because it returns an `Object[]` not a `String[]`. No generic method works nicely either because you cannot create a `new T[]`. Unless you find a method specific to `String`, the nicest possible call would look something like `foo(LibraryClass.add(ARRAY_ARGS, additionalArgument, new String[1 + ARRAY_ARGS.length]));`

Comment: @pbabcdefp It will work. There is an overloaded version of ArrayUtils.addAll() which returns String[]. See [docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html).

Comment: Apologies. You are right, it will work. But it returns a `T[]` not a `String[]`. They must use reflection to create the new `T[]`.

Answer (score 3):

A variable argument is equivalent to an array. Hence, the compiler does not accept an array *and* a string. One solution is to create an array from the original with the additional string added to it:

```
List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList(ARRAY_ARGS);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(originalList);
Collections.copy(list, originalList);
list.add(additionalArgument);
foo(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```

The `Collections.copy` is needed because adding to the list returned by `Arrays.asList` throws a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` as the latter returns a list that extends `AbstractList` which does not support adding elements.

Another solution is to create a new array and individually add the elements:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
arr[0] = ARRAY_ARGS[0];
arr[1] = ARRAY_ARGS[1];
arr[2] = additionalArgument;
foo(arr);
```

Or you can simply call `foo` with the individual parameters:

```
foo(ARRAY_ARGS[0], ARRAY_ARGS[1], additionalArgument);
```

Comment: @Kao In this case you can expect it to be 3, but setting it to zero won't harm because it will automatically create an array that fits the elements.

Comment: A more generic way to get the right array with the respective length would be list.toArray(new String[list.size()])

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if the first argument to your method is the single string, followed by the varargs:

```java
public static void foo(String a, String... args) {
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    System.out.println("args = " + Arrays.toString(args));
}
```

Then calling `foo("a", "b", "c")` prints

```
a = a
args = [b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `String ... args` is shorthand for `String[]`. Therefore you get an error when you are calling `foo(args,additionalargument)` since the method declaration of `foo` is `foo(String[] str)` instead of `foo(String[],String)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you must distinguish between the array and the single string, concatenate the array values in a format you can "recognize", pass the "array-string" and the single string as parameters to the main method, and then parse the "array-string" in the relevant (foo) method.

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 approach to solve this problem is the following oneliner:

```
foo(Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(ARRAY_ARGS), Stream.of(additionalArgument)).toArray(String[]::new));
```

This creates a new `String[]` that can be passed to `foo`. Furthermore, `foo` must be made `static`, otherwise the code will not compile.

The only parameters that you can pass to the `foo`-method is either a `String` array or a bunch of individual `String`s.